# Does differing mains frequency affect DC motors?

Tags: ac, mains, rectifier, frequency-response

I moved a large, high-quality kitchen appliance (a stand mixer) intended for use in North America to the UK. To operate it without damage to the motor, I will need to (at least) convert the voltage from 220 v to 110 v.

However, the AC frequency is 50 hz here, as opposed to 60 hz in North America. As I understand, this would also cause problems for an AC motor, but should not cause problems for a DC motor.

My limited understanding of the circuit to convert AC power to DC power is that first a rectifier ensures the polarity is fixed, and then a capacitor smooths the signal. It seems like the capacitance (and other components) would be tuned to the expected frequency. That is, the voltage coming out of this circuit is supposed to be constant when the input is 60 hz, but maybe with a 50 hz input the output will still have a slight periodic component.

Is this an issue to worry about? How much of an effect might this have on the output and performance of the machine?

Comment: No. DC is fine too. Going super low on the frequency would be interesting and not very useful but DC, 50-60 Hz is fine.

Comment: DC has no frequency, OK you could say that the frequency is 0 Hz (zero Hertz). But are you asking about a circuit inside that appliance? Are you implying that the mixer uses a DC motor? That's possible but highly unlikely as AC motors are generally more reliable and cheaper (simpler construction) than DC motors. Even **if** the mixer has a DC motor you should use the mixer with 120 V AC. Step down transformers exist but watch the power ratings. I'd generally advice to buy a new/used device designed for the UK.

Comment: At this moment it is unclear (to me) what you're asking. Indeed "frequency" doesn't apply / matter to DC motors (DC has no frequency). But it is unclear how this relates to the kitchen appliance. It is also unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's probably _not_ a DC motor.  Please edit your question to include the make & model.  Nearly all brushed motors that run off of AC are "universal" shunt-wound motors designed to run off of either DC or AC.  If that's the case, just dropping the voltage down to 120V, 50Hz should work fine.

Comment: Approximately every few months someone asks a nearly identical product usage question. What on earth is so special with these that people want to take kitchen equipment with them?

Comment: @Justme They are expensive and work very well, and there may not be comparable local equivalents, or it may be cheaper to have them shipped along with the rest of your belongings, than selling it locally, and then buying an equivalent in Europe.

Comment: @Justme KitchenAids are practically a cult. (230V ones are available in the UK, but considerably more expensive than in the US)

Comment: Universal motor are frequency indipendent (up to a limit) since they are mechanically commutated so it should work

Answer (score 1):

KitchenAid and similar stand mixers require high torque and thus use universal motors. These motors can run from DC up to several hundred Hz AC directly without any external rectification. The actual mains frequency is thus of no concern. Just make sure the voltage is 120V AC :) There is a speed regulator, and those typically need AC to operate, but 50 vs 60Hz won't do much difference to them.

Comment: If I recall correctly from looking in the back of my Kitchen Aid mixer (ca 1987 or so) it's a centrifugal switch with contacts that will probably still be good when Zephram Cochrain first shakes hands with a Vulcan.

Comment: @TimWescott Pretty much :)